# Accessing resource with a single URL over two networks -- home network and remote (wireguard) network

Tags: dns, routing, android, wireguard, dnsmasq

### Wireguard network

I am currently trying to setup a wireguard tunnel in this format. The reason I am using wireguard is to tunnel through my home's NAT (I do not have a static IP or access for port forwarding)

`android` -> `vps-server`

`home-server` -> `vps-server`

all the devices on the wireguard tunnel are on the subnet `10.200.200.0/24`. IPs are set statically and hard-coded:

```
wireguard on vps-server  : 10.200.200.1
wireguard on home-server : 10.200.200.2
wireguard on android     : 10.200.200.3
```

### Home network

At my home network, I have a DNS/DHCP server (`dnsmasq`) hosted on `home-server`. All hosts on the home network are on the subnet `10.0.0.0/24`.

```
home-server : 10.0.0.1
android     : 10.0.0.2
```

### My Issue

If I am at home on `android`, I can access my server using `home-server.local` and the dnsmasq will return the correct IP: `10.0.0.1` and I can connect to the services hosted on my server.

But when I am remote, I want to keep the same URL (`home-server.local`). If `android` asks `home-server` for the ip address of `home-server.local` it will get the reply `10.0.0.1`. Which is not accessible via the remote network. Adding a route into wireguard android app works on the remote network, but when `android` is on the local network, the route interferes with any local network access as its always routed through wireguard and not the native interface.

Most apps like `nextcloud` do not have dual URL options (I believe `home assistant / hass` has this option). The dual hostname option would allow me to use a different URL for different networks. I want to seamlessly transition from my home network to the remote network and access my home resources (`home-server` -- `home-server.local`) from the same URL in a clean manor with minimal additional dependencies.

### Example

If my `nextcloud` service is accessed via `home-server.local:8081`, I can access it from that URL inside my network (`home-server.local` -> `dnsmasq`-> `server` via `10.0.0.1`). However if I move outside my home network I want (`home-server.local` -> `??DNS Magic??` -> `10.200.200.2` -> routed through wireguard vps -> `server` via `10.200.200.2`)

### ~~Ideas~~

On a Linux laptop, I can add routes when on a remote network so I can access `10.0.0.1` THROUGH the wireguard tunnel. And remove routes on connection to my home network, but I do not believe this is possible on stock Android. I do not understand routes very well so this may just be a ignorance issue.

One option I have thought of is adding a DNS entry in `dnsmasq` that prevents my `android` device from connecting to the VPN when on my home network, but this seems like a hacky solution which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

> On a Linux laptop, I can add routes when on a remote network so I can access 10.0.0.1 THROUGH the wireguard tunnel. And remove routes on connection to my home network, but I do not believe this is possible on stock Android. I do not understand routes very well so this may just be a ignorance issue.

You can achieve this by having two WireGuard tunnel configurations (with different AllowedIPs, which the WireGuard app translates directly to routes), then using something like the 'Automate' or 'Tasker' apps to activate a different tunnel depending on which Wi-Fi SSID you're on.

Although in this case, it doesn't look like you *need* the tunnel at home; so you could similarly automate just the switching on/off of a single tunnel that always has the 10.0.0.1 route.

Another similar approach is to route things the opposite way, and always use the WireGuard IP address even at home by configuring your home gateway so that the server's WireGuard address is routed via the same server's LAN address – this will then result in a direct LAN connection. (As above, you would then automate the switching on/off of the WireGuard tunnel when away.)